# Cannot find my home wifi network on one of two laptops with the same OS

Tags: wifi

I have 2 laptops setup with a fresh debian 8 installation. (*junon & mercure*)

I can access any wifi network displayed in the list (iwlist scan) on both machines.

On `junon`, `iwlist scan` displays all wifi networks. On `mercure`, it displays all of them except my home wifi network. Embarrassing ...

- My box is of course set up with wifi "hidden network" to NO, as **DataCenter** (my home network) is reachable on junon.
- Locales are the same : `en-US.utf-8`

Any idea about this issue ?

scan outputs :

- [`iwlist scan` on junon](http://downloads.open-si.org/pub/scan-wifi.junon) — my home network:

  ```
    Cell 01 - Address: F4:CA:E5:BD:2F:D4
              Channel:13
              Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)
              Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
              Encryption key:on
              ESSID:"DataCenter"
              Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                        6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
              Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
              Mode:Master
              Extra:tsf=000000accfb80a95
              Extra: Last beacon: 13824ms ago
              IE: Unknown: 000A4461746143656E746572
              IE: Unknown: 010882848B962C0C1218
              IE: Unknown: 03010D
              IE: Unknown: 2A0104
              IE: Unknown: 3205243048606C
              IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                  Group Cipher : CCMP
                  Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                  Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
              IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
              IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
  ```
- [`iwlist scan` on mercure](http://downloads.open-si.org/pub/scan-wifi.mercure)
- `lshw -C network` on mercure

  ```
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 05
         serial: 5c:26:0a:11:8e:3b
         size: 1Gbit/s
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-1 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
         resources: irq:40 memory:f6900000-f691ffff memory:f6970000-f6970fff ioport:7020(size=32)
    *-network
         description: Wireless interface
         product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
         vendor: Broadcom Corporation
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
         logical name: wlan0
         version: 01
         serial: c0:cb:38:54:29:20
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
         configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
         resources: irq:17 memory:f4100000-f4103fff
  ```
- `rfkill -list` on mercure:

  ```
  0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  1: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [question and answer site](/tour), not a discussion forum. If an answer solves your problem, click the “accept” checkmark next do it, don't edit the title. For more information, see the [help center](/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *DataCenter* WiFi network is on Channel 13. Not all WiFi channels are permitted in all countries; some countries permit only channels 1-11, for example.

Check that *mercure* is configured for the same country (and locale) as *junon*. Also try changing the *DataCenter* channel, even just temporarily.

Comment: Perhaps , but as mentionned  it does work with  other equipments in my home network: Samsyung & Apple tablets, multiple smartphones , a raspberry py . with French and US locals .. and so one.. so inside my home network, channel 13 is reachable with different ones. but I'm gonna check this. Thanks for your answer

Comment: roaima maybe right. My wife´s notebook was bought in the USA, and refuses to see channel 13 and 14. It is not a matter of being broadcasted or not at home, it is because by FCC specs you do not use channel 13 and 14. I ended up giving her a 5GHz USB pen, and nowadays we operate at 5GHz at home.

Comment: Thought locales where the same it looks you were right Roaima .. switching to channel 9 fixed the problem. thanks a lot !